# How to take \n from excel using java?

Tags: java

I am reading excel data where I am giving `Hi\nI'm good`. But when Java reads this from excel it is taken as `Hi\\nI'm good`. Due to which one of my assertion fails.I need to read the exact sentence what I have given in excel.

Comment: Where is the difference?

Comment: found it, was only visible while editing

Answer (score 0):

As you don't give enough context here is a guess:

If you enter `\n` into the Excel you will receive the escaped variant in Java and thus have to check for `\\n`

If you expect to receive a newline you will have to create it in Excel by pressing`Ctrl`-`Enter`(Excel is not using escape sequences)